A very specific spring boot actuator / swagger integration question
I'm launching my springboot webapp and navigating to localhost/api/myservice/swagger-ui/index.html, but getting a 401 Unauthorized. I've done all the usual things from now countless answers on SO, but none seem to apply specifically to this pairing of spring and spring doc. One limitation I have is Java 1.8, else I would use newer versions of software. Handcuffs.
Short version:
spring-boot: 2.7.18
spring-doc: 1.8.0
pom.xml snippets:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


When I checked, the oldest version of springboot for springdocs was past Java 1.8.
application.yml snippets:
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs/**
  swagger-ui:
    enabled = true
    path = /swagger-ui.html
    tryItOutEnabled = false
    filter = false
    syntaxHighlight.activated = true
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/myservice

SwaggerConfig.java snippets:
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi api() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("my/package/**")
                .pathsToMatch("/**")
                .packagesToExclude("/error.**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI apiInfo() {
        final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
        return new OpenAPI()
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
                .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes(
                        securitySchemeName,
                        new SecurityScheme()
                                .name(securitySchemeName)
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                                .scheme("bearer")
                                .bearerFormat("JWT")
                ))
                .info(new Info()
                        .title(title)
                        .version(version)
                        .description("")
                )
                .servers(Collections.singletonList(
                        new Server()
                                .url(contextPath)
                                .description("Default Server URL")
                ));
    }
}

SpringConfiguration.java snippets:
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// I have tried very many things here, but I don't see how it could get much more permissive than this ;)
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        return http
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMatcher requestMatcher() {
        this.log.debug("Creating request matcher");
        List<RequestMatcher> requestMatchers = new ArrayList<>();
        requestMatchers.add(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
        return new OrRequestMatcher(requestMatchers);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter(
            RequestMatcher requestMatcher,
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter result = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(requestMatcher);
        result.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager());
        return result;
    }

}

When I uncomment the CustomAuthenticationFilter stuff, I get the 401 Unauthorized hitting localhost/api/myservice/swagger-ui/index.html, because that class is being applied, but when I comment it out, I hit the swagger page just fine.
I'm new to this version of SpringBoot and new to Swagger 3 and new to springdocs. I have this working in other microservices that use a FilterRegistrationBean instead of something like CustomAuthenticationFilter, and I'm not sure why the same configurations don't work in this repository. Bonus points if this can be done without disabling csrf.
When I navigate to localhost/api/myservice/swagger-ui/index.html I get a 401 Unauthorized. I expect the Swagger page to load without needing authorization.
When I comment out the CustomAuthenticationFilter bean, I get the expected result. I'm not sure why beyond being certain that the CustomAuthenticationFilter is being used to secure Swagger pages when I don't want it to.
I have also tried
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer(@Value("${server.servlet.context-path}") String contextPath) {
        return web -> web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", contextPath + "/swagger-ui/**");
    }

which issues printed warnings on the console about using authorizeHttpRequests instead. And I've tried that as well.
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/swagger-ui/index.html",
                        contextPath + "/swagger-ui/index.html",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/api/**",
                        contextPath + "/swagger-ui/**"
                ).permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }


with swagger-3 better use springboot 3.x

@AnubhavSharma Thanks for the compatibility suggestion. I hope it helps someone. The earliest version of springboot 3.x that doesn't have a security vulnerability is 3.0.13. It depends on version 6.0.14 of spring-core which is compiled against java 17. While I would love to update our Java version, I'm stuck using Java 8.

first thing you have to do is to exclude  swagger endpoint from your security context (SecurityFilterChain), you already did the configuration in WebSecurityCustomizer , no need to do it again .
what you need  is :
  @Bean
  public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
  return (web) ->
    web.ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui.html")
        )
  ; 
  }

application.properties (you can change it to yml) :
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tryItOutEnabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs

finaly you can keep your OpenAPI() as it is or :
    @OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                contact = @Contact(
                        name = ""
                ),
                description = "",
                title = "",
                version = "",
                license = @License(
                        name = "",
                        url = ""
                ),
                termsOfService = "Terms of service"
        ),
        servers = {
                @Server(
                        description = "Local ENV",
                        url = ""
                ),
                @Server(
                        description = "PROD ENV",
                        url = ""
                ),
                @Server(
                        description = "TEST ENV",
                        url = ""
                )
        },
        security = {
                @SecurityRequirement(
                        name = "bearerAuth"
                )
        }
)
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "bearerAuth",
        description = "JWT auth description",
        scheme = "bearer",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

 @Bean
public GroupedOpenApi api() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("us/cargosphere/**")
            .pathsToMatch("/**")
            .packagesToExclude("/error.**")
            .build();
}

}

In addition to the changes provided by Mohamed, I also needed to change my request matcher.
@Bean
public RequestMatcher requestMatcher() {
    // if (!swagger && !error) then apply CustomAuthenticationFilter
    return new NegatedRequestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(Arrays.asList(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api-docs/**"),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error")
    )));
}

